# List to list dictionary (Python optimization)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, dictionary, optimization

I'm trying to convert a list of lists of strings (that represents a tic-tac-toe game) to a list of lists of integers, so that I can perform calculations.

These are the possible inputs:

```
A = ['X', 'O', '#']
```

And these the corresponding integers:

```
B = [1, 0, 99]
```

So overall it would do the following:

```
[['X', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', '#', 'X']] -> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 99, 1]]
```

I have created the following functions to perform this translation, but I'm sure there must be a faster and more efficient way:

```
def make_integer_matrix(inputs):
    A = ['X', 'O', '#']
    B = [1, 0, 99]
    integer_matrix = []
    #First translate to integers
    for row in inputs:
        row_new = [B[A.index(row[0])], B[A.index(row[1])], B[A.index(row[2])]]
        integer_matrix.append(row_new)
    return integer_matrix
```

Comment: `in_arr = [["X", "O", "O"], ["O", "X", "O"], ["O", "#", "X"]]`, `out_arr = [[0 if e == "O" else 1 if e == "X" else 99 for e in row] for row in in_arr]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider creating a mapping dictionary and using a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
>>> mapping = {'X': 1, 'O': 0, '#': 99}
>>> raw_board = [['X', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', '#', 'X']]
>>> value_board = [[mapping[c] for c in row] for row in raw_board]
>>> value_board
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 99, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is that I was looking for. Just a bit more elegant

Answer (score 3):

Instead of constantly searching the first array to determine the corresponding index, create a dictionary from the two lists and use that for the translation:

```
A = ['X', 'O', '#']
B = [1, 0, 99]
# create translation table from lists
translations = dict(zip(A, B))

for row in inputs:
    row_new = [translations[v] for v in row]
    integer_matrix.append(row_new)
return integer_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ['X', 'O', '#']
B = [1, 0, 99]

game_map = [['X', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', '#', 'X']]


def map_values(A, B):
    result_dict = dict()
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        result_dict[a] = b
    
    return result_dict

char_to_int_map = map_values(A, B)

game_map_int = [[char_to_int_map[x] for x in row] for row in game_map]

print(game_map_int)
```